# query works in the browser but not with the official driver

Tags: neo4j

I'm executing a cypher query which runs successfully hundreds of times. Every so often ( not the same parameters ) the official driver (.net) will puke an

> **"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat"**
>
> Unable to deserialize request, message boundary found before message ended. This indicates a serialization or framing problem with your client driver.

when i copy the query text to the browser interface the query executes without a hitch.

Any pointer in the right direction on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

*(didn't want to litter the question with useless data but will gladly post whatever you deem necessary)*

**here is the code and exception**

```
using (var s = _driver.Session())
{
    try
        {
            var result = s.Run(q.Query.QueryText, q.Query.QueryParameters).Consume();
        //... 
    }
    catch(ClientException cex) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(cex.ToString());
        //...
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
        //...
    }
}
```

> Neo4j.Driver.V1.ClientException: Unable to deserialize request, message boundary found before message ended. This indicates a serialization or framing problem with your client driver.
>      at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.SocketClient.Receive(IMessageResponseHandler responseHandler) in Z:\BuildAgent\work\9ae188c903d07190\Neo4j.Driver\Neo4j.Driver\Internal\Connector\SocketClient.cs:line 114
>      at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Connector.SocketConnection.Sync() in Z:\BuildAgent\work\9ae188c903d07190\Neo4j.Driver\Neo4j.Driver\Internal\Connector\SocketConnection.cs:line 68
>      at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Session.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0() in Z:\BuildAgent\work\9ae188c903d07190\Neo4j.Driver\Neo4j.Driver\Internal\Session.cs:line 83
>      at Neo4j.Driver.Internal.LoggerBase.TryExecute[T](Func`1 func) in Z:\BuildAgent\work\9ae188c903d07190\Neo4j.Driver\Neo4j.Driver\Internal\LoggerBase.cs:line 54
>      at vizipi.hosts.owned.neo.Service.exeWithDriver(ICypherFluentQuery q) in C:\Users\adam\Source\Repos\vizipihosts\vizipi.hosts.internal.neo\Service.cs:line 195

**this is what the request looks like**

```
MATCH (pr:blah {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
}.mykey})
MERGE (f250:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f250.name = "x1"
ON MATCH
SET f250.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]"
ON CREATE
SET f250 = {
  name: "x1",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]"
}
MERGE (f250)-[Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]-[39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]-[39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]-[39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2.sha = "39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df"
ON MATCH
SET Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2.numz = 54
ON CREATE
SET Aebee44ae626d4a9c9c62921f3a65caf2 = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x1]-[39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "39eea4824cdc6ff003461585c94f42e729b164df",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 54
}
MERGE (f251:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f251.name = "x2"
ON MATCH
SET f251.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]"
ON CREATE
SET f251 = {
  name: "x2",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]"
}
MERGE (f251)-[A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]-[46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]-[46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]-[46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b.sha = "46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372"
ON MATCH
SET A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b.numz = 51
ON CREATE
SET A2d6e63b607774024a311cd8aa7f76a4b = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x2]-[46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "46a72e86be8401df81b64dc54b4cf3c4eaa0a372",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 51
}
MERGE (f252:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f252.name = "x3"
ON MATCH
SET f252.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]"
ON CREATE
SET f252 = {
  name: "x3",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]"
}
MERGE (f252)-[A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]-[ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]-[ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]-[ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94.sha = "ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b"
ON MATCH
SET A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94.numz = 31
ON CREATE
SET A5e60396572b54776bc069a1b43898a94 = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x3]-[ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "ca34cc922c02de29ae40394dd7f04cf91b4f4d8b",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 31
}
MERGE (f253:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f253.name = "x4"
ON MATCH
SET f253.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]"
ON CREATE
SET f253 = {
  name: "x4",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]"
}
MERGE (f253)-[A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]-[a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]-[a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]-[a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af.sha = "a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df"
ON MATCH
SET A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af.numz = 21
ON CREATE
SET A20ddcfea727340d6b15eeee02f24c2af = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x4]-[a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "a508ea4beb536042f0c3cf71a045f7ef403838df",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 21
}
MERGE (f254:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f254.name = "x5"
ON MATCH
SET f254.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]"
ON CREATE
SET f254 = {
  name: "x5",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]"
}
MERGE (f254)-[Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]-[7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]-[7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]-[7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216.sha = "7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45"
ON MATCH
SET Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216.numz = 36
ON CREATE
SET Ab096b10ac1b4498597fb165f50daf216 = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x5]-[7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "7db9345f860f60b16ad8ce5dafa9bceec72c7d45",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 36
}
MERGE (f255:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f255.name = "x6"
ON MATCH
SET f255.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]"
ON CREATE
SET f255 = {
  name: "x6",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]"
}
MERGE (f255)-[A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]-[9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]-[9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]-[9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722.sha = "9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b"
ON MATCH
SET A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722.numz = 26
ON CREATE
SET A0b3583558a8b4a13801c30a3acf07722 = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x6]-[9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "9975b94d62ba9980bf5207699a8306ada116656b",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 26
}
MERGE (f256:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f256.name = "x7"
ON MATCH
SET f256.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]"
ON CREATE
SET f256 = {
  name: "x7",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]"
}
MERGE (f256)-[A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]-[c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]-[c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]-[c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242.sha = "c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5"
ON MATCH
SET A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242.numz = 103
ON CREATE
SET A0a655e5410b54e65aa41cfd5b383f242 = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x7]-[c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "c9bb318942f4b2cb3bdbb0948f22eb3f490ff3c5",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 103
}
MERGE (f257:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f257.name = "x8"
ON MATCH
SET f257.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]"
ON CREATE
SET f257 = {
  name: "x8",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]"
}
MERGE (f257)-[Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]-[d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]-[d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]-[d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e.sha = "d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53"
ON MATCH
SET Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e.numz = 44
ON CREATE
SET Ab7acecee33e24abb967da9c14348071e = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x8]-[d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "d255c91da5c247138a3988352299395416696c53",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 44
}
MERGE (f258:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f258.name = "x9"
ON MATCH
SET f258.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]"
ON CREATE
SET f258 = {
  name: "x9",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]"
}
MERGE (f258)-[Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]-[73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]-[73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]-[73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da.sha = "73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b"
ON MATCH
SET Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da.numz = 15
ON CREATE
SET Acf68e132ca1a49d3a4e5025596bed0da = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x9]-[73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "73cd31ac02e7221be7b799801ac0b23f92f1363b",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 15
}
MERGE (f259:Friend {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]"
}.mykey})
ON MATCH
SET f259.name = "x10"
ON MATCH
SET f259.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]"
ON CREATE
SET f259 = {
  name: "x10",
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]"
}
MERGE (f259)-[A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861:COMMITED {mykey:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]-[1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2"
}.mykey,tokenx:{
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]-[1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2"
}.tokenx}]->(pr)
ON MATCH
SET A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861.mykey = "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]-[1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]"
ON MATCH
SET A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861.sha = "1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2"
ON MATCH
SET A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861.numx = 0
ON MATCH
SET A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861.numy = 0
ON MATCH
SET A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861.numz = 77
ON CREATE
SET A6a004b0e898b4fbbb37b7683f6c78861 = {
  mykey: "[a]-[b]-[c]-[x10]-[1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2]-[a]-[b]-[c]-[e84e899bef927197870ded7dc0b7f9b1db8b5900]",
  tokenx: "1ae55ace69b17badcc285958ab1e17bdfda371b2",
  numx: 0,
  numy: 0,
  numz: 77
}
```

Comment: well please paste the code you use for sending the query with the driver

Comment: what's inside QueryParameters ? and what's your query ?